# Url for download Symfony1.4 checker of configuration returns 401: Authorization required

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am reading documentation of symfony1.4 becouse I've to learn it due to a legacy code. At some point documentation says:

```
Then, download the symfony configuration checker script at the following URL:
```

So I'd tried to run

```
$ curl -d "" http://sf-to.org/1.4/check.php
```

I received the message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4/data/bin/check_configuration.php">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Then, I've tried to run

```
$ curl -d "" http://svn.symfony-project.com/branches/1.4/data/bin/check_configuration.php
```

getting this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's best to use the git repository of symfony:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony1

The `check_configuration.php` file can be found here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/data/bin/check_configuration.php

or if you want just the contents of the file:

https://raw.github.com/symfony/symfony1/1.4/data/bin/check_configuration.php

Comment: It's right. But link does not work just because is not yet supported that version of Symfony.